# Install ubuntu on pendrive and use remaining disk space to store files, instead of persistence file

Tags: live-usb, usb-drive

Is there any way where I can install Ubuntu on my pendrive / USB stick, and then have my files, settings, etc. saved across reboots?

I want the files to be easily accessible from other computers, so they should be directly on the pendrive partition, not inside a persistence file. That way, I can use my computer to copy files to /home/ubuntu/Desktop and then be able to see them on my desktop when I boot from the pendrive. This is how Puppy Linux works if you install it on an ext2/3/4 filesystem.

If it's not possible, then can I create another partition on my pendrive an use it for /home/ubuntu in my live system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a flash drive using persistent partitions not limited to the 4GB of FAT32 files.

Partition an 8GB or larger drive first half FAT32, second half ext2, label the ext2 partition casper-rw, (you can make a third partition named home-rw if you want a seperate home).

Install to the first partition using usb-creator, (Startup Disk Creator), or UNetbootin, allowing minimum persistence space. when done delete the casper-rw file located in root.

To make a folder easily accessable from other computers, create a folder in filesystem/cdrom. You will see this folder in the flash drive root when plugged into a running Linux or Windows computer.

You can not access the casper-rw file where /home/ubuntu/Desktop is located from a Windows machine, (easily).